# While making POJO parcelable I am getting exception Unexpected character ('<' (code 60))

Tags: android, parcelable

When I am making `parcelable` one field I am getting this error

> Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number,
>   String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')

I have tried without making `parcelable` field so I am not getting this error, but I have to make that field `parcelable`

**this is my `parcelable` implementation**

public class CommTransaction extends CommAgent implements Parcelable {

```
public String getCpBnkCodDes() {
    return cpBnkCodDes;
}

public void setCpBnkCodDes(String cpBnkCodDes) {
    this.cpBnkCodDes = cpBnkCodDes;
}

private String cpBnkCodDes;

public String getcBranch() {
    return cBranch;
}

public void setcBranch(String cBranch) {
    this.cBranch = cBranch;
}

public String dBranch;
public String cBranch;

public Double txnAmount;

public String transId; // RefId

public String serverTxnId; // CBS

public String dAccountNo;

public String dName;

public String dLoc;

public String dCurrency;

public String dMob;

public String bAccountNo;

public String bName;

public String bLoc;

public String bMob;

public String bCurrency;

public String bIdType;

public String bIdNum;

public Date initTime;

public String moduleType; // moduleCode

public String dIdType;

public String dIdNum;

public String remarks;

public String txnStatus;

public String paymentType;

public String depLastName;

public String benfLastName;

public String chargeType;

public String validationType;

protected String securirityQuestion;

protected String securirityAns;

protected String secType;

protected String uniqueId;

protected Double txnFee;

protected String deductProcess;

protected String txnCcy;

protected String cusBnkCod;

protected String cpBnkCod;

protected String loanAccountNumber;

protected String lnBrn;

protected Date valDate;

protected List<AbLoanSettelments> settlements;

protected String upVendorType;

protected String cifId;

protected String otp;

protected String otpvalidty;

public String getUpType() {
    return upType;
}

public void setUpType(String upType) {
    this.upType = upType;
}

public String getBillNo() {
    return billNo;
}

public void setBillNo(String billNo) {
    this.billNo = billNo;
}

protected String upType;
protected String billNo;

public String getBillerNumber() {
    return billerNumber;
}

public void setBillerNumber(String billerNumber) {
    this.billerNumber = billerNumber;
}

protected String billerNumber;


public CommTransaction() {

}

public Double getTxnAmount() {
    return txnAmount;
}

public void setTxnAmount(Double txnAmount) {
    this.txnAmount = txnAmount;
}

public String getTransId() {
    return transId;
}

public void setTransId(String transId) {
    this.transId = transId;
}

public String getServerTxnId() {
    return serverTxnId;
}

public void setServerTxnId(String serverTxnId) {
    this.serverTxnId = serverTxnId;
}

public String getdAccountNo() {
    return dAccountNo;
}

public void setdAccountNo(String dAccountNo) {
    this.dAccountNo = dAccountNo;
}

public String getdName() {
    return dName;
}

public void setdName(String dName) {
    this.dName = dName;
}

public String getdLoc() {
    return dLoc;
}

public void setdLoc(String dLoc) {
    this.dLoc = dLoc;
}

public String getdCurrency() {
    return dCurrency;
}

public void setdCurrency(String dCurrency) {
    this.dCurrency = dCurrency;
}

public String getdMob() {
    return dMob;
}

public void setdMob(String dMob) {
    this.dMob = dMob;
}

public String getbAccountNo() {
    return bAccountNo;
}

public void setbAccountNo(String bAccountNo) {
    this.bAccountNo = bAccountNo;
}

public String getbName() {
    return bName;
}

public void setbName(String bName) {
    this.bName = bName;
}

public String getbLoc() {
    return bLoc;
}

public void setbLoc(String bLoc) {
    this.bLoc = bLoc;
}

public String getbMob() {
    return bMob;
}

public void setbMob(String bMob) {
    this.bMob = bMob;
}

public String getbCurrency() {
    return bCurrency;
}

public void setbCurrency(String bCurrency) {
    this.bCurrency = bCurrency;
}

public String getbIdType() {
    return bIdType;
}

public void setbIdType(String bIdType) {
    this.bIdType = bIdType;
}

public String getbIdNum() {
    return bIdNum;
}

public void setbIdNum(String bIdNum) {
    this.bIdNum = bIdNum;
}

public Date getInitTime() {
    return initTime;
}

public void setInitTime(Date initTime) {
    this.initTime = initTime;
}

public String getModuleType() {
    return moduleType;
}

public void setModuleType(String moduleType) {
    this.moduleType = moduleType;
}

public String getdIdType() {
    return dIdType;
}

public void setdIdType(String dIdType) {
    this.dIdType = dIdType;
}

public String getdIdNum() {
    return dIdNum;
}

public void setdIdNum(String dIdNum) {
    this.dIdNum = dIdNum;
}

public String getRemarks() {
    return remarks;
}

public void setRemarks(String remarks) {
    this.remarks = remarks;
}

public String getTxnStatus() {
    return txnStatus;
}

public void setTxnStatus(String txnStatus) {
    this.txnStatus = txnStatus;
}

public String getPaymentType() {
    return paymentType;
}

public void setPaymentType(String paymentType) {
    this.paymentType = paymentType;
}

public String getDepLastName() {
    return depLastName;
}

public void setDepLastName(String depLastName) {
    this.depLastName = depLastName;
}

public String getBenfLastName() {
    return benfLastName;
}

public void setBenfLastName(String benfLastName) {
    this.benfLastName = benfLastName;
}

public String getChargeType() {
    return chargeType;
}

public void setChargeType(String chargeType) {
    this.chargeType = chargeType;
}

public String getValidationType() {
    return validationType;
}

public void setValidationType(String validationType) {
    this.validationType = validationType;
}

public String getSecurirityQuestion() {
    return securirityQuestion;
}

public void setSecurirityQuestion(String securirityQuestion) {
    this.securirityQuestion = securirityQuestion;
}

public String getSecurirityAns() {
    return securirityAns;
}

public void setSecurirityAns(String securirityAns) {
    this.securirityAns = securirityAns;
}

public String getSecType() {
    return secType;
}

public void setSecType(String secType) {
    this.secType = secType;
}

public String getUniqueId() {
    return uniqueId;
}

public void setUniqueId(String uniqueId) {
    this.uniqueId = uniqueId;
}

public Double getTxnFee() {
    return txnFee;
}

public void setTxnFee(Double txnFee) {
    this.txnFee = txnFee;
}

public String getDeductProcess() {
    return deductProcess;
}

public void setDeductProcess(String deductProcess) {
    this.deductProcess = deductProcess;
}

public String getTxnCcy() {
    return txnCcy;
}

public void setTxnCcy(String txnCcy) {
    this.txnCcy = txnCcy;
}

public String getCusBnkCod() {
    return cusBnkCod;
}

public void setCusBnkCod(String cusBnkCod) {
    this.cusBnkCod = cusBnkCod;
}

public String getCpBnkCod() {
    return cpBnkCod;
}

public void setCpBnkCod(String cpBnkCod) {
    this.cpBnkCod = cpBnkCod;
}

public String getLoanAccountNumber() {
    return loanAccountNumber;
}

public void setLoanAccountNumber(String loanAccountNumber) {
    this.loanAccountNumber = loanAccountNumber;
}

public String getLnBrn() {
    return lnBrn;
}

public void setLnBrn(String lnBrn) {
    this.lnBrn = lnBrn;
}

public Date getValDate() {
    return valDate;
}

public void setValDate(Date valDate) {
    this.valDate = valDate;
}

public List<AbLoanSettelments> getSettlements() {
    return settlements;
}

public void setSettlements(List<AbLoanSettelments> settlements) {
    this.settlements = settlements;
}

public String getUpVendorType() {
    return upVendorType;
}

public void setUpVendorType(String upVendorType) {
    this.upVendorType = upVendorType;
}

public String getCifId() {
    return cifId;
}

public void setCifId(String cifId) {
    this.cifId = cifId;
}

public String getOtp() {
    return otp;
}

public void setOtp(String otp) {
    this.otp = otp;
}

public String getOtpvalidty() {
    return otpvalidty;
}

public void setOtpvalidty(String otpvalidty) {
    this.otpvalidty = otpvalidty;
}


public String getdBranch() {
    return dBranch;
}

public void setdBranch(String dBranch) {
    this.dBranch = dBranch;
}

protected CommTransaction(Parcel in) {
    cpBnkCodDes = in.readString();
    dBranch = in.readString();
    cBranch = in.readString();
    txnAmount = in.readByte() == 0x00 ? null : in.readDouble();
    transId = in.readString();
    serverTxnId = in.readString();
    dAccountNo = in.readString();
    dName = in.readString();
    dLoc = in.readString();
    dCurrency = in.readString();
    dMob = in.readString();
    bAccountNo = in.readString();
    bName = in.readString();
    bLoc = in.readString();
    bMob = in.readString();
    bCurrency = in.readString();
    bIdType = in.readString();
    bIdNum = in.readString();
    long tmpInitTime = in.readLong();
    initTime = tmpInitTime != -1 ? new Date(tmpInitTime) : null;
    moduleType = in.readString();
    dIdType = in.readString();
    dIdNum = in.readString();
    remarks = in.readString();
    txnStatus = in.readString();
    paymentType = in.readString();
    depLastName = in.readString();
    benfLastName = in.readString();
    chargeType = in.readString();
    validationType = in.readString();
    securirityQuestion = in.readString();
    securirityAns = in.readString();
    secType = in.readString();
    uniqueId = in.readString();
    txnFee = in.readByte() == 0x00 ? null : in.readDouble();
    deductProcess = in.readString();
    txnCcy = in.readString();
    cusBnkCod = in.readString();
    cpBnkCod = in.readString();
    loanAccountNumber = in.readString();
    lnBrn = in.readString();
    long tmpValDate = in.readLong();
    valDate = tmpValDate != -1 ? new Date(tmpValDate) : null;
    if (in.readByte() == 0x01) {
        settlements = new ArrayList<AbLoanSettelments>();
        in.readList(settlements, AbLoanSettelments.class.getClassLoader());
    } else {
        settlements = null;
    }
    upVendorType = in.readString();
    cifId = in.readString();
    otp = in.readString();
    otpvalidty = in.readString();
    upType = in.readString();
    billNo = in.readString();
    billerNumber = in.readString();
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(cpBnkCodDes);
    dest.writeString(dBranch);
    dest.writeString(cBranch);
    if (txnAmount == null) {
        dest.writeByte((byte) (0x00));
    } else {
        dest.writeByte((byte) (0x01));
        dest.writeDouble(txnAmount);
    }
    dest.writeString(transId);
    dest.writeString(serverTxnId);
    dest.writeString(dAccountNo);
    dest.writeString(dName);
    dest.writeString(dLoc);
    dest.writeString(dCurrency);
    dest.writeString(dMob);
    dest.writeString(bAccountNo);
    dest.writeString(bName);
    dest.writeString(bLoc);
    dest.writeString(bMob);
    dest.writeString(bCurrency);
    dest.writeString(bIdType);
    dest.writeString(bIdNum);
    dest.writeLong(initTime != null ? initTime.getTime() : -1L);
    dest.writeString(moduleType);
    dest.writeString(dIdType);
    dest.writeString(dIdNum);
    dest.writeString(remarks);
    dest.writeString(txnStatus);
    dest.writeString(paymentType);
    dest.writeString(depLastName);
    dest.writeString(benfLastName);
    dest.writeString(chargeType);
    dest.writeString(validationType);
    dest.writeString(securirityQuestion);
    dest.writeString(securirityAns);
    dest.writeString(secType);
    dest.writeString(uniqueId);
    if (txnFee == null) {
        dest.writeByte((byte) (0x00));
    } else {
        dest.writeByte((byte) (0x01));
        dest.writeDouble(txnFee);
    }
    dest.writeString(deductProcess);
    dest.writeString(txnCcy);
    dest.writeString(cusBnkCod);
    dest.writeString(cpBnkCod);
    dest.writeString(loanAccountNumber);
    dest.writeString(lnBrn);
    dest.writeLong(valDate != null ? valDate.getTime() : -1L);
    if (settlements == null) {
        dest.writeByte((byte) (0x00));
    } else {
        dest.writeByte((byte) (0x01));
        dest.writeList(settlements);
    }
    dest.writeString(upVendorType);
    dest.writeString(cifId);
    dest.writeString(otp);
    dest.writeString(otpvalidty);
    dest.writeString(upType);
    dest.writeString(billNo);
    dest.writeString(billerNumber);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public static final Parcelable.Creator<CommTransaction> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<CommTransaction>() {
    @Override
    public CommTransaction createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new CommTransaction(in);
    }

    @Override
    public CommTransaction[] newArray(int size) {
        return new CommTransaction[size];
    }
};
 }
```

Comment: Post your parcelable implementation

Comment: Any help would be appreciable...

Comment: That Pojo is too long , how can I post?

Comment: Can You share Your mail id?

Comment: show the code, and the data you are trying to parse

Comment: I have edited my post, now You can find parcelable implementation

Comment: when I am gonna add this field  "protected List<CommTranUdf> trnudf;" and then making parcelable I am getting this "error Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')"

Comment: Looks like you parsing JSON with incorrect type. Check `CommTranUdf` class values and compare with input data

Comment: Incorrect type means?should I check CommTranUdf Pojo and their values?